# Debug.DrawRay() pointing to wrong direction in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am trying to learn how to Raycast in Unity2D.

Here is my code:

```cs
Ray ray;
void Update()
{
    ray = new Ray(transform.position, Input.mousePosition);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position,Input.mousePosition);
}
```

This results in strange behavior.
transform.position is the Vector3 of the player object.

I want to shoot a ray from the Player Object through the Mouse Position.

However, this does not seem to work.

The line is drawn, but behaves weirdly.  It does not point toward it at all.  It's hard to accurately describe its behavior as anything except erratic.

What am I doing wrong?

I think there may be something wrong with putting in Input.mousePosition and directions in general.  I would be very thankful for any help  you can give.

Note: I am using Unity 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Input.mousePosition` you get a `Vector2` which represents the position of the mouse relative to the camera. This means the X and Y you get are actually the X and Y of the position of the mouse on the screen.

These coordinates are not world coordinates.

For example if you were to draw a ray from `transform.position` of a player standing at `0,0,0` to the mouse position of `500, 250` you would get a gigantic and seemingly randomly pointing ray.

[image: Example Showing Screen Coordinates vs. World Coordinates]

To convert from where the mouse is on the screen(Screen Coordinates) to what it's pointing to in-game(World Coordinates) [you can use `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

For example

```cs
Ray ray;
void Update()
{
    // get the mouse screen pos
    Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    
    // convert it
    Vector3 worldMousePosition = Camera.Main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

    ray = new Ray(transform.position, );
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, worldMousePosition);
}
```